# Errno2 no such file or directory in python. Can't open .py or .csv or .tar.gz

Tags: python

```
Donnas-MBP:~ donna$ cd Applications
Donnas-MBP:Applications donna$ python3 app.py
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python: can't open file 'app.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

app.py is saved in Applications. I know it's there. All of my .csv and .py files are there. I know because it was working before. But now nothing is working. I tried absolute path and that did not work. I'm using high sierra.

I tried running ls

```
Donnas-MBP:Applications donna$ ls
Documents   Utilities
```

My files were not here. This used to work fine. Not sure what happened.

Comment: After you `cd Applications`, run `ls` to see what files are located there.

Comment: As you can see after running `ls`, `Applications` only contains two folders

Answer (score 0):

FRom the result of `ls` you posted, there are no files in `Applications` just those two directories. Perhaps the files you seek are in those directories not `Applications`.

Comment: I moved a file to applications then it worked fine. I was super confused because this used to work perfectly for me.